# how to pass arguments while creating gmail watch to push notification

Tags: python, push-notification, google-api, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

What i did so far:

- Prerequisites : DONE
- Create a topic : DONE
- Create a subscription : DONE
- given push endpoing url : DONE
- Grant publish rights on your topic : DONE
- got result while creating response : {'historyId': '714707', 'expiration':
  '1618824687477'}

```
    curl --location --request POST 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'state: object' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <user_token>'
\
--data-raw '{
    "attributes": {
        "key1": "value1"
    },
    "labelIds": [
        "INBOX"
    ],
    "labelFilterAction": "INCLUDE",
    "topicName": "projects/appletio/topics/axdspplet" }'
```

i am able to push notification response like this

```json
{   "message": {
    "data": "eyJlbWFpbEFkZHJlc3MiOiJvbXByYWthc2hrYWx1dmFAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaGlzdG9yeUlkIjoyNDA1OTAxfQ==",
    "messageId": "2296976769072743",
    "message_id": "2296976769072743",
    "publishTime": "2021-04-14T11:36:09.297Z",
    "publish_time": "2021-04-14T11:36:09.297Z"   },   "subscription": "projects/appletio/subscriptions/applet-sub" }
```

but we are unable to get attribute key and value in push notification response
Is there any way to get that attribute keys and value
or
Is there any way  to send any extra attributes/parameters  while creating a watch in Gmail
ANY HELP IS appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no "attributes" field specified in the documentation : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/watch

Maybe you can add attributes to the topic name:

`"topicName": "projects/appletio/topics/axdspplet-key-value"`

Comment: Tried, with your suggestion it's throwing 404 not found error  i have topic call applet  CHECK THIS URL---> https://snipboard.io/8EJPKh.jpg

Comment: But you have to create all the topics you need. If you have so many possible attributes (topics) then this solution is not good.